# Reading files name that begin with DOT "."

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have this simple nodeJS script for reading files from a PATH and check if they are directory or not :

```
var fs = require("fs");  
var allFiles = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/bb');
allFiles.forEach(function(name){
if(fs.lstatSync(name).isDirectory())
    {
        console.log(name);         
    }
});
```

The problem is when I check if the file is DIRECTORY **.isDirectory()** and the file begins with a **DOT** "**.**"

```
fs.js:679
return binding.lstat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
             ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'D:\test\.ggg'
at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:679:18)
at D:\test\server.js:4:11
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\test\server.js:3:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

If I don't check if DIRECTORY or the file name don't begin with a DOT "." it works just fine.
OS : Windows 7

Comment: can you try `path.join("bb",name)` in `.lstatSync..` ?

Comment: It works now with path, seems like not the DOT was the problem, the problem was like you said wrong path in .lstatSync, ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `.lstatSync` with the wrong path.

Try `path.join` instead to create the correct path.

The snippet should look like

```
var fs = require("fs");  
var allFiles = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/bb');
allFiles.forEach(function(name){

if(fs.lstatSync(path.join("bb",name)/*Correct path*/).isDirectory())
    {
        console.log(name);         
    }
});
```